# Laravel 5.5 Relationships - ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel

Can't display an info from DB to view, have an error

> ErrorException
>   Trying to get property of non-object

Let me explain the logic:

1. User can create many companies
2. Companies can have many items

I don't have problems with inserting info to DB, everything is fine.
I can display every info from Users table and Company table in my Show View, but I can't display info from Company_Items tables in my view.
I guess something is wrong with my Relationships or keys, but what?
Trying to display Item name that belong to the specific company

```
{{$company->company_items->name}}
```

Company Table:

- id(int)
- company_name(string)
- info(text)
- user_id(int)

Company_items Table:

- id(int)
- company_id(int)
- name(string)

Company Model:

```
class Company extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'company';

//relation. MANY companies can be created by ONE user
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

//relation. ONE company can have MANY items
public function item(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
}
```

Item Model:

```
class Item extends Model
{
 protected $table = 'company_items';

//relation. MANY items can be applied TO ONE company 
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {

   $company = Company::find($id);
   $user = User::find($id);
   $company_items = Item::find($id);

   return view('company_show')->with(['company' => $company,'company_items' => $company_items]);

}
```

View:

```
This is <b>{{$company->company_id}}</b> page info created by <b>{{$company->user->name}}</b><br>
                        Company category is <b>{{$company->company_category}}</b>.<br>
                        Item name is <b>{{$company->company_items->name}}</b>. // Can't display this expression
```

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$company->company_items` is a list of all the items of the company, you can't call a param on it. And you declared your relation with the name `item` and not `company_items`

Try to do :

```
$company->item[0]->name
```

or

```
@foreach($company->item as $item)

{{ $item->name }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, your solution works as well.
And thanks, for telling me about relation name ;)

Answer (score 0):

First error you made is:

```
$company_items = Item::find($id);
```

This will return the company Item that has the ID=$id which means it will return the Item that has the same ID as the company! I'm sure that's not what you want.

Instead you can do:

```
$company_items = $company->item;
```

which will return all the items of that company

and in your view you can access the items with a foreach loop:

```
@foreach($company_items as $item){
   {{$item->name}}
}
```

Comment: For example:
I have 2 companies: Samsung(id 1) and Apple(id 2) (values in table Company)
And I have an items: iPhone 6, iPhone 7, Samsung Galaxy s8, Samsung Galaxy s7 (values in table Company_items)
I want to show in Apple page only iPhones and in Samsung page only Galaxy.
I have a relation so iPhones have company_id 1 and Samsung = company_id 2

Comment: that's exactly what I wrote in the answer mate.
Lets say Apple company has ID=1 so Iphone 6 will have company_id=1
that's what the relationship means, just paste the code I wrote and it will work :)

Comment: Ok, probably didn't understand you cause of my english, I'll test it and answer ;)